# PHPUnit 6.4.1 no tests executed

Tags: php, phpunit

I am getting this warning when i run phpunit on command line :

```
PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Time: 114 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

No tests executed!
```

here is my framework folders structure :

```
.
├── App
├── CHANGELOG
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── Config
├── Database
├── local.env.php
├── phpunit.xml
├── public
├── README.md
├── robot.txt
├── silver
├── Storage
├── System
├── Tests
└── vendor
```

Test directory :

```
Tests
└── Unit
    └── ControllerTest.php
```

phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./Tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

composer.json file :

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "Tests/"
    }
}
```

controllerTest class :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;


class ControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test  */
    public function testFirstMethod()
    {
        $num = 20;

        $this->assertEquals(22, $num);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or help would be very appreciated thanks.

Comment: It surely works for me. I used phpunit 5.5.7.

Comment: Title says PHPUnit `6.4.1` and your command line says `5.1.3` ?!?

Comment: @bish yeah you are right vendor version is 6.4.1 while phpunit CLI version is 5.1.3 i dont know if those sould be the same because on linux when you `apt-get install phpunit` you get 5.1.3 by default !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have different installations of PHPUnit mixed up.

For instance, you may have used Composer to install PHPUnit and have configured the autoloader generated by Composer as PHPUnit's bootstrap script but then you invoke PHPUnit using an executable other than `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian !!! what a nice answer from PHPUnit founder    i have solved it thank you so much !